# htaccess mask for my url

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, mask

I'm trying to mask a part of my url using .htaccess but I'm having several issues

my url is
http://ristorantitalianetwork.com/ristorantitalianetwork.com/admin/

I'd like to remove the duplicate ristorantitalianetwork.com, so I'd like that my url will be like

http://ristorantitalianetwork.com/admin/

I've used

```
RewriteRule ^ristorantitalianetwork.com/([^/]*)$ ?q=$1 [L]
```

but it doesn't work

Could you please help me to figure out how to solve this problem?

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You really need

```
RewriteRule ^/admin$ /ristorantitalianetwork.com/admin [L]
```

Bear in mind that the URL you should expose to users is `http://ristorantitalianetwork.com/admin/` which will then internally get converted (rewritten) to `http://ristorantitalianetwork.com/ristorantitalianetwork.com/admin/`.

It is not the other way round as many believe.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the hint, but it doesn't work, as you can see http://ristorantitalianetwork.com/admin/           I don't know how to solve this...

Comment: Perhaps you can enable `RewriteLog` and see to which URL it is trying to rewrite to.

Answer (score 0):

You almost did it! But...

In your question, your rewriterule says that it is applied on URLs that don't end with a slash (`/`). And you say you want to rewrite some URLs... and give URLs examples with a slash (`/`).

If you need to do a **real** redirect (i.e. the URL in  the browser changes):, here's the good rewriterule:

```
RewriteRule ^ristorantitalianetwork\.com/([^/]*)/$ /$1 [QSA,R=301,L]
```

If you need to do only internal redirect:

```
RewriteRule ^ristorantitalianetwork\.com/([^/]*)/$ /$1 [QSA,L]
```

Keep in mind that the URL **must** end with a slash (`/`).