# How to remove path information from url?

Tags: php, javascript, apache

How do I remove path inforation from a url?

For example in this url, `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`, I want the user to only see `http://stackoverflow.com`.  Is this possible to do?

I do a redirect in PHP from my root directory to path Foo.  I don't want Foo to display in the URL.I also do a page reload of sorts using `window.location.href = domain_name/foo`.  Similarly I don't want foo to display in the URL.

Is this possible to implment in Javascript or PHP or do I have to configure Apache to do this?

Comment: anonymous down voting brings out the *******

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot manipulate URLs in the browser's address bar using PHP or JavaScript. But you have guessed correctly, this is something that can be configured in Apache. For a primer on URL rewriting, take a look at [this article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have seen websites that keep the user on the homepage and use AJAX to change the page content.

Answer (score 0):

You should make yourself sober and then consider if you *really* want to hide anything and if your web site would work at all.

However, I can answer you already - it wouldn't.
We are using path information for the reason. And you'd better see it.

Comment: What's up Shrap dog!  Work on that grammar.

Answer (score -1):

Read up on URL masking:

[htaccess mask for my url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615812/htaccess-mask-for-my-url)

http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/URL-masking.php

etc... This cannot be handled in JS.

If you REALLY wanted to, you could do this in PHP: you would need to create an index.php page that was set up to handle the loading of other pages, and add a handler at the top of every page that detects the REQUEST_URI that sets any other link to redirect (header()) to the index page with the filepath stored in $_SESSION or another retrievable location. The index page would then render the requested page. However, this is ugly, wastes resources, and you're much better off with an apache level rewrite.

Comment: Hmm.... -1? I suppose I'm being penalized for not insisting that Drunken Coder abandon his schemes to mask his url? While it's probably not a great idea in most scenarios, for non-public tools it may have its use... a question was asked, an answer was given.

Comment: anonymous down voting brings out the *******

Comment: From javascript you can set the url of the page without redirecting. See `history object` for that (history.pushState).

Comment: @khael: How would you go about that? As I understand it, the history object simply lets you access the browser history (it's like hitting the back or forward button on your browser). How would this mask the URL?

Comment: history.pushState({pagex: "index.php?lang="},"","index.php?lang=");

Comment: @BenD check the comment above, forget to notice you about it, sorry